# Properly gathering metadata/object data using Core Data/sqlite

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

I'm new to objective c and core data. I am making an iOS app kind of like a flash card app. I have a core data set up with an EnglishWord entity in a many to one relationship with ForeignWord entities (different languages).

For each ForeignWord entity I want to keep track of certain metadata: how many times I have viewed the word, the dates I viewed it, a score I give it, etc. Ideally would be if I could have an array/dictionary as an attribute within the ForeignWord managed object itself. This is not possible.

The only option I can think of is to create a new entity called 'Score', with each ForeignWord entity 'owning' many Score managed objects (one to many), a new 'Score' managed object being created every time I view the foreignWord.

However, this sounds very messy. If I have 1000 words then I would have 1000 different tables in the sqlite database, one for each card.. does that slow things down? is it bad to have 1000 different tables?

is this really the way to do it? Is there a more elegant solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create one new table called ViewEntry or something and link relationships to both of your word tables. That way when a word is viewed you can store whatever meta information you want, as well as having an active link to the English and foreign version. Something like this:

[image]

This way you can create a new ViewEntry set its `foreignVersion` and `word` attributes to the English and foreign words, set the date, score, and total answer time (along with anything else you want). You could then do some really nice querying to pull up useful information.

> - give me all of the foreign versions of the English word "school" where the score was less than 50%.
> - I want all of the times the user attempted the Russian translation of "house" and the associated scores.
> - what English words have the worst/best score?
> - what is the most/least view English (or foreign) word?

All of this would be relatively easy since the English word could access all of the times it was viewed and any foreign version of any English version could do the same. You could also access the score and view date and pull up all of the English/foreign versions from that data.

You also would not need to create 1000 tables :)

Comment: hm.. that looks awfully pretty.. uhh I think its kind of what I had in mind.. I must be confused with how core data works. I think I need to tinker around a little more, and then I'll give you the green check mark thing. Thanks a lot for the tips!

Comment: well play around and let me know if you have any questions. I will try to address them.

Comment: hey that worked perfectly, thanks a lot for the well explained answer

Answer (score 1):

You might consider adding a table called something like "Viewing" that has a relationship (to 1) both to EnglishWord and ForeignWord. You could then track the metadata that interest you in this table and aggregate the data in this table to determine how many times that you viewed a particular word, whether or not you identified it correctly, etc.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. my only question is, will this not create a 'viewing' table for each 'englishword' and 'foreignword'? so that at the end i have thousands of 'viewing tables'? or am I missing something... thanks again

Comment: No. You only need one table.